# Django - Restructured queryset is not iterable

Tags: python, django, iteration

I have a Django queryset. I'm using `groupby` to restructure the queryset:

```
content_items = ContentItem.objects.filter(content_group__row__page=page)
```

`content_items` looks like this:

```
[<Faq: Faq object>, <Text: Text object>, <Faq: Faq object>, <Faq: Faq object>]
```

Group `content_items` by `content_group` attribute:

```
content_groups = {}
for group, items in groupby(content_items, lambda x: x.content_group):
    content_groups[group] = list(items)
```

`content_groups` looks like this:

```
{<ContentGroup: 16>: [<Faq: Faq object>, <Faq: Faq object>], <ContentGroup: 17>: [<Text: Text object>], <ContentGroup: 18>: [<Faq: Faq object>]}
```

Iterating over `content_groups`...

```
for content_group in content_groups:
    for content_item in content_group:
        print content_item
```

... produces `'ContentGroup' object is not iterable`, I can not see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content_groups` is a *dictionary*, when you iterate it over via:

```
for content_group in content_groups:
```

`content_group` would correspond to each *key* - a `ContentGroup` instance. And, you get an error when you try to loop over it - a Django model instance is not iterable.

Instead, you meant to [iterate over dictionary items](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

```
for content_group, faq_objects in content_groups.items():
    print(content_group)
    for faq_object in faq_objects:
         print(faq_object)
    print("----")
```